# viewing specific people who have shared/liked a page on facebook & retweeted

Tags: facebook, twitter, facebook-sharer

I'm planning to run a promotion on my site that will require me to know EXACTLY who has "shared" specific pages on my site on facebook and retweeted the page on twitter.

The most I've been able to find so far is a way to get the count of people as opposed to the actual names of the individuals who's shared the pages.

Does anyone know of a way to

1. Get a listing of the SPECIFIC people that have shared a page from my site on facebook?
2. Get a listing of the SPECIFIC people that have retweeted a page from my site on twitter?

Answer (score 0):

No **specific** way, but here's a manageable/complex way.

As for twitter, you can you can use [Yahoo! Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/). Set up a feed with regex patterns matching some key strings in your tweet and run the pipe. The data returned would be tweets that match, from there you can get the User ID's. I'm blank as regards to Facebook.

**NOTE** :: Search retweets are preceeded by `RT`

Hope you can implement this.